# why is this not running correctly? thoughts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

why is this not running correctly? the price is $80 on the website and I have it set for < 81 but it still is not working correctly, thoughts?

This is my first program in python so I am extremely nooby to it. This is a webscraper made with BeautifulSoup. let me know if you need anymore information.
I put a fake email in the code below for privacy purposes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import time

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Hubcaps-com-Premium-Quality-Hubcaps- 
Construction/dp/B06XRTYSHH/ref=sr_1_1? keywords=2017+nissan+sentra+hubcaps&qid=1572841095&replacementKeywords=hubcaps&sr=8- 
 1&vehicle=2017-67-899------------&vehicleName=2017+Nissan+Sentra'

headers = {
"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}


def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(span="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(span="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[0:2])

if converted_price < 81:
    send_mail()

print(converted_price)
print(title.strip())
if converted_price < 81:
    send_mail()


def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login(fakeemail@gmail.com', 'pcsziqijxiebnvun')

subject = 'Price Drop'
body = 'Check it out here: https://www.amazon.com/Hubcaps-com-Premium-Quality-Hubcaps-Construction/dp/B06XRTYSHH/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=2017+nissan+sentra+hubcaps&qid=1572841095&replacementKeywords=hubcaps&sr=8-1&vehicle=2017-67-899------------&vehicleName=2017+Nissan+Sentra'

msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

server.sendmail(
    'fakeemail@gmail.com',
    'fakeemail@live.com',
    msg
)
print('EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT!')

server.quit()

while(True):
    check_price()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: `converted_price` is a local variable in your `check_price` function. This function is not being called anywhere, so the variable is not assigned. But even if you did call the function, the variable would not be accessible outside of the function.

Comment: you should use `return converted_price` inside `check_price()` and then you can use `converted_price = check_price()`. And you have to use `converted_price < 81` after you use `converted_price = check_price()`

Comment: shortly: you check converted price before you get price from web page. You runs lines of code in wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I see few mistakes in code.

First your problem from question: you check price before you get it. It should be something like.

```
while True:
    price = check_price()

    if price < 81:
        send_mail()

    time.sleep(60)
```

You also compare `81` with variable which exists only inside function - you should use `return` to assign value to external/global variable

```
 def check_price():
     # ...rest...
     return float(price[0:2])
```

and then you can do

```
    price = check_price()

    if price < 81:
        send_mail()
```

---

I found also other problems.

To get title and price I had to use `lxml` instead of `http.parser`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
```

and

```
title = soup.find('span', {'id': "productTitle"}).get_text()
price = soup.find('span', {'id': "priceblock_ourprice"}).get_text()
```

---

With these changes I found another problem - page in your URL doesn't have price so second `find()` gives `None` and I have `None.get_text()` which shows error.

I had to check result from `find()` before I use `get_text()`,

```
price = soup.find('span', {'id': "priceblock_ourprice"})

if price:
    price = price.get_text()
    price = float(price[0:2])
```

and

```
#if (price is not None) and (price < 81):
if price and price < 81:
    send_mail()
```

---

After that it has no problem to find price.

I would expect only problem with `gmail` - if you didn't test this part of code - because currently Google has more restricted rules for access to gmail and you have to go to Google/Gmail account and generate special password only for your script (if you set "2-factory protection" for Gmail). It may not work with password which you use to access Gmail in web browser.

---

Here full code with all changes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import time

# --- functions ---

def check_price(URL):

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
    }

    response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    title = soup.find('span', {'id': "productTitle"})
    if title:
        title = title.get_text()
        title = title.strip()
    print('title:', title)

    price = soup.find('span', {'id': "priceblock_ourprice"})
    if price:
        price = price.get_text()
        price = float(price[0:2])
    print('price:', price)

    return title, price


def send_mail(URL, title, price):

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('fakeemail@gmail.com', 'pcsziqijxiebnvun')

    subject = 'Price Drop'
    body = f'Check it out here: {URL}\nTitle: {title}\nPrice: {price}'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
        'fakeemail@gmail.com',
        'fakeemail@live.com',
        msg
    )
    print('EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT!')

    server.quit()

# --- main ---

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Hubcaps-com-Premium-Quality-Hubcaps-Construction/dp/B06XRTYSHH/ref=sr_1_1? keywords=2017+nissan+sentra+hubcaps&qid=1572841095&replacementKeywords=hubcaps&sr=8-1&vehicle=2017-67-899------------&vehicleName=2017+Nissan+Sentra'

while True:
    title, price = check_price(URL)

    if price and price < 81:
        send_mail(URL, title, price)

    print('sleep')
    time.sleep(60)
```